# How to declare the type of this variable within map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Here is the function in question:

```
  const getCountryLangCode = (countryCode: string) => {
    const filtered = Object.entries(config.languages)
      .map(([key, language]) => {
        if (language.code.split('-')[1] === countryCode) {
          return language.code
        }
      })
      .filter(item => item)
  
    const langCode = filtered[0]
  
    return langCode
  }
```

The problem is that 'language' within the map() function is type = unknown, and when I try to **build my React app** it is failing to build due to this type `Object is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571`

I've tried every version of the typing syntax that I can think of to feed 'any' type to 'language' but I'm doing it wrong.

What's the proper way to declare that language should be type == any ?

Comment: Why do you "filter" the array in `.map()` and then once again with `.filter()` to fix your faulty usage of `.map()`?

Comment: You want `Array.prototype.find()` instead your `.map().filter()[0]` construct

Comment: Thanks @Andreas - it's someone else's code I was trying to debug.  I didn't understand it very well either, precisely because the usage of map was overly complicated for the expected result.  The answers below solve the question, but in the end I realized that this entire function was way too complicated when all we want is a single value from a known key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Declare Types Higher-Up

You always want to declare the type higher-up in the chain when you can.  You are asking to "declare the type of this variable within `map()`" but you want to declare the type of the `config` variable.  Having a proper type on the `config.languages` object will allow Typescript to infer the types of `Object.entries`, `.map()`, and `.filter()` on its own.

`config` is an `object` with a property `languages`.  That `languages` property is an `object` where each value is an `object` with a property `code` which is a `string`. We use the Typescript type [`Record<Keys, Values>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) when we have an object where all values are the same type.

```
interface MyConfig {
  languages: Record<string, {code: string}>
}
```

#### Writing the Function

There may be other properties that you want to include to help out other functions, but that's all we need to know here.

As pointed out by @Andreas, `.map()` is not the ideal function here.  If you wanted to find all matches you would use `.filter()` directly on the entries.  Since you only want to first you should use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).  You don't look at the `key` at all so you can use `Object.values` instead of `Object.entries`.

```
const match = Object.values(config.languages).find(
  language => language.code.split('-')[1] === countryCode
);
return match?.code;
```

If `config` has type `MyConfig` then the variable `languages` in the `find()` callback will automatically get the type `{ code: string }` because Typescript knows the value type of the `config.languages` object.

We use the [optional chaining `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) because `find` is not guaranteed to find a match, so `match` might be `undefined`.  Our function returns `string | undefined`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N9AEoN)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question to put type on `Object.entries` you do it like this

```js
...
const filtered = Object.entries<{ code: string }>(config.languages)
      .map(([key, language]) => {
...
```

see there `<YourType>` before ( and after `entries`. This way you will put specific type on incoming `entries` parameter, in your case `config.languages`